# jQuery php request with safety

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a user account system and admin levels. What I want to do is delete images with jquery and PHP requests but I worry about the security, since people can use firebug to see what's being send (User ID, Picture ID, etc...) and done in PHP so what would be a better way of doing this without worrying much about this? I could just use PHP but I want it to be animated and without refreshing the page.

Comment: What scenario in particular are you worried about?  The only stuff that should be sent to the user is stuff you want the user to see things like image_id .  If you are properly verifying and validating your inputs (prepared queries), the worst that can happen is someone sends a request to delete an image that they don't own.  Which you can account for with redmoon7777's suggestion.

Comment: Silent downvotes should be banned. Upvoting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you don't want a user to delete an image that is not his, just check whether he owns it or not. something like :
`SELECT * FROM table WHERE image_id='$image_id' AND user_id='$user_id'`

the $user_id should contain the user id stored in your session (the one you used for auth)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to do:

1.You need administrator to delete the photo,like auditing，so you just get user_id from cookie or session(not the POST parameter),and check its privilege(to be a adminstrator) and then decide what to do

2.You need the user to delete the photo that belong to himeself,in this case it's identical to  what redmoon7777 said,you just check the user_id in cookie or session,see if it's the same with the photo's creator

Answer (score 0):

For best security, all allowed actions should be server aware - some way or another.

Most probably, the users session-data would be involved,

- Checking their (session stored) grant group and allowing the ajax-request.
- Having a hash for every specific ajax command, based for the specific state.

If you don't want to bother with session-logic, I belive your best attempt of security (partly flawed) is to hash the ajax request with a random private key. someting like

md5(thepk & thedate & theprivatekey) => as &hash= in ajax url

on ajax request, validate the params by re-calculating the hash.

//t

Answer (score 0):

eencode ur function parameters like photo_id using base64_encode (or other way) and in server side decode it. By this way if the user saw ur param he can't do aything with ur parameters.